# owner of a file is changed to root automatically

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions

In using ubuntu 12.10 , i written an API using node.js...

I have a logfile to capture all errors, the owner for the file is "my system user". At some occasions it is changed to "`ROOT`" automatically, so my node.js application don't have permission to access that file and my application is exited.

How the owner of the file is changed to root automatically.

Please share some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you run your application?

Comment: @ zhujs Thanks  i am running supervisor as root(sudo).

Comment: Where is the logfile stored? Is it maybe affected by logrotate?

Comment: logfile is stored in /home/username(*)/log-dir/log-file